# clearRect behaving strangely/not working

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

`ctx.clearRect()` only cleared half (like half of canvas.width..left side) of canvas.

Has anyone had this kind of problem before? all my `beginPath` are closed (I saw somewhere that this can be a problem (?) ) and I'm using standard call:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

any ideas what can be a problem or some alternative?

code is too big to put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

Change it to:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Correct Syntax is:

`context.clearRect(x, y, width, height)`